# In javascript, is there an easy way to get the table element from one of the rows?

Tags: javascript

In my code, I am doing stuff to a table based upon a column or row click.
I only saw the way of getting the table using `parentElement`

So I might have

```
<div id="table-container">

</div>
```

```
let table = document.createElement('table');
table.id = 'my-table';


let thead = table.createTHead();
let thead_row = thead.insertRow();
let thead_cell = thead_row.insertCell();
thead_cell.textContent = "Products";

let tbody = table.createTBody();
let tbody_row1 = thead.insertRow();
let tbody_cell1 = tbody_row1.insertCell();
tbody_cell1.textContent = "apple";
let tbody_row2 = thead.insertRow();
let tbody_cell2 = tbody_row1.insertCell();
tbody_cell1.textContent = "orange";

document.getElementById('table-container').appendChild(table);
```

So here I have an easy reference to the table which I might not have in my code elsewhere and I do not want to pass the table all over.

So let's say I put an eventlistener on a row like so:

```
tbody_row2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(tbody_row2.parentElement.parentElement.id);
})
```

to get the table id from the row itself (if I did not have the easy table reference), I need to use
`[element].parentElement.parentElement.id`
which to me is not always clear it is a table.

To get the rows out of a table, I can write.

```
table.rows;
```

Is there anything similar to:

```
row.table;
```

for an upward reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `.closest` element method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

If you have an row element, you can run this command against that row element and it will return the first parent element with the selector you pass in

```
const row = table.rows[0];
const parentTable = row.closest('table');
```

Comment: okay, thanks. I will incorporate this in my code as it is clear what it is doing! thanks